# Everything return into one list

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I currently encounter an issue that everything returns to the same list. I know it is because I add everything into the same array. But how to add them to specific location like the one in my firebase.

```
public class GroupAdp extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GroupAdp.ViewHolder> {
    //Initialize activities and array list
    private Activity activity;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListGroup;
    MemberAdp adapterMember;
    //Create constructor
    GroupAdp(Activity activity,ArrayList<String> arrayListGroup){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.arrayListGroup = arrayListGroup;
//        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_row_group,parent,false);
        return new GroupAdp.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //Set group name on TextView
        holder.tvName.setText(arrayListGroup.get(position));

        //Initialize member ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> arrayListMember = new ArrayList<>();

        //Using for loop to add multiple members
//        for (int i=1; i<=6; i++){
//            arrayListMember.add("Member " + i);
//        }

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Course_ID_Section");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String UID = user.getUid();

                for (DataSnapshot courseSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: courseSnapshot.getChildren()) {
//                        arrayListMember.add(userSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
                        if(UID.equals(userSnapshot.getKey())) {
                            arrayListMember.add(userSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
                        }

                    }
                }
                adapterMember.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        //Initialize member adapter
        adapterMember = new MemberAdp(arrayListMember);

        //Initialize layout manager
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerMember = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);

        //Set layout manager
        holder.rvMember.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerMember);

        //Set adapter
        holder.rvMember.setAdapter(adapterMember);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayListGroup.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //Initialize variable
        TextView tvName;
        RecyclerView rvMember;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //Assign variable
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            rvMember = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_member);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

```
public class HealthAlertActivity2 extends Fragment {

    //Initialize variable
    RecyclerView rvGroup;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListGroup;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerGroup;
    GroupAdp adapterGroup;

    //@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View healthAlertFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.healthalert_activity2, container, false);


        //Assign variable
        rvGroup = healthAlertFragment.findViewById(R.id.rv_group);

        //Using for loop to add multiple group
        //Used for dummy display for now

//        for (int i= 1; i<=6; i++){
//            arrayListGroup.add("Group " + i);
//        }


        ArrayList<String> arrayListGroup = new ArrayList<>();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Course_ID_Section");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {


                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String UID = user.getUid();

                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
                Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Value:" + map);

                assert map != null;
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    Log.e("The Result", entry.getKey());

                    arrayListGroup.add(entry.getKey());

                }
                adapterGroup.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });


        //Initialize group adapter
        adapterGroup = new GroupAdp(getActivity(), arrayListGroup);

        //Initialize layout manager
        layoutManagerGroup = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        //Set layout manager
        rvGroup.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerGroup);

        //Set adapter
        rvGroup.setAdapter(adapterGroup);
        return healthAlertFragment;
    }
}
```

```
public class MemberAdp extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MemberAdp.ViewHolder> {
    //Initialize ArrayList
    ArrayList<String> arrayListMember;

    //Create constructor
    public MemberAdp(ArrayList<String> arrayListMember) {
        this.arrayListMember = arrayListMember;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Initialize view
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_row_member,parent,false);
        return new MemberAdp.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //Set member name on TextView
        holder.tvName.setText(arrayListMember.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayListMember.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //Initialize variable
        TextView tvName;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //Assign variable
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I want to return all students who have the same class as the user in the firebase and return them to different list based on how they are stored in firebase.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you subscribe to the root of your data `Course_ID_Section`, so you get all the data in the same way without respect to its Courses ids. There are a few ways how to handle it, but in your case, I would recommend the following:

Store students not in the same array `arrayListMember`, but in Hashtable (or another associative array implementation), or in a new `Course` class. Then, fill in your new data structure when you are looping through courses in your line `arrayListMember.add(userSnapshot.getValue(String.class))`, because at this point you have a data about a student, and `courseSnapshot` to get the name of a course